# Question is not clear option

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, notifications

Currently there is an option to close the question if the question is not clear.

But I think it would be nice to have an additional notification which helps to notify the user that "Your question needs to improve". That would be a much better way to do it.

Since close votes may close the question, even after the user updated the question with more details.

So please add an another link which the close voter can use to notify the user.

Comment: I like how this has a close vote *unclear what you're asking*

Comment: Close voting is *meant* to tell you there's something to improve, in a much better way than just flat out "this needs improvement". [status-completed]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's exactly what that close vote is *for*. As Glorfindel mentioned, comments focusing on specific areas that aren't clear are fairly common, and there are also [requests to show closures to askers earlier](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed).

Beyond that, though, the real question is this: do we want answers coming in to a question that *needs* to be improved? The answer is *no*, we do not. There is a distinction made between downvoting questions and closing them, and it's between questions that aren't that great, and questions that are sufficiently bad they're *not answerable*. (Among other things.) So a question that's poorly phrased but still understandable can *already* be downvoted without voting to close, but a question that's not clear enough to be understood should be closed to new answers.

Answer (score 9):

Usually, when I see a question which is not clear, but *could be* if the OP edited his question, I'll leave a comment asking for clarification (in addition to my close vote). Even if the close-voter doesn't leave a comment, with [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) you'll be able to see the close votes on your own question anyway.

If the OP *really* succeeds in making the question more clear, other people won't cast any more close votes, and the close votes cast before the edit will age away eventually. And if the question is closed before the OP can make the edit, the edit will send the question into the reopen queue, where it gets another chance at being reopened.